# DotNetNuke Secure Module Folder

Tags: permissions, directory, dotnetnuke

I have created a module in DNN which has a sub-folder that contains several files which are used by the module, but which I do not want accessible by the public. Being new to DNN I had originally thought to simply add a Web.config and set deny users="*" in the authorization section. It looks to me now though that DNN intercepts all the requests and ignores the Web.config as this setting seems to have no effect.

Users can currently access these files simply by guessing a file name and navigating to (http://mysite.com/DesktopModules/mymodule/restricted_files/guessedfile.pdf). How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetNuke allows you to have [different providers for folders](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Folder-Types.aspx) in the file system.  If you use those providers (instead of interacting with the file system directly), then you can make sure that DNN has control of the permission to the files in the folder.

Built into DNN are three providers, Standard, Secure, and Database.  If you create a folder with the Secure or Database provider, then DNN will make sure that you can't get to the file just by guessing the path (either by appending `.resources` to the filename, which IIS won't serve, or by putting it in the database).  You can then assign permissions to the folder (via the File Manager page in the Admin menu) to indicate who can get to those files (the site administrator will always be able to access the files, unless you're using the Host file system).

However, these folder providers only apply to the `Portals` directory in the site.  It's recommended that you'd store content files there, rather than in `DesktopModules`.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. These files will get distributed with the module. How would I direct the installer to put these files into a secure filesystem folder under Portals as you suggest?

Comment: Your module's business controller class can implement [`IPortable`](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/IUpgradeable.aspx) to run code after the installation.  You can also in the manifest indicate via the `<basePath>` element that a file should end up in a particular folder, e.g. Portals/_default/MyFiles (see [the wiki page on the File component of the manifest](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Manifest-File-Component.aspx))